# Linear extensions of divisor poset of a positive integer

Tags: co.combinatorics, posets

Consider $n = p^k$ where p is prime and $k \ge 2$. Let $D_n =\{ p, \dots, p^{k-1}\}$ be the set of proper divisors of $n$. Now, the divisor poset in the set $D_n$ is linearly ordered and further satisfies given $1 \le i \le k-1$ there is a $1 \le j \le k-1$ such that $n$ divides $p^i p^r$ for all $r \ge j$.

Now, consider the set $D_n$ for an arbitrary positive integer $n$ and its divisor poset. Now this poset is not linearly ordered in general. My question is there a linear extension of this poset or any other linear order on $D_n$ such that if the divisors are written as $d_1,\dots,d_s$ in this order then given $1 \le i \le s$ there is a $1 \le j \le s$ such that $n$ divides $d_i d_r$ for all $r \ge j$?

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand your question. Take $n=6$, Then $s=2$, and we might as well take $d_1=2$ and $d_2=3$. Now take $i=2$. Whether we take $j=1$ or $j=2$, we can take $r=2$. But $6$ does not divide $d_2^2=9$.

Comment: Yes. What you are saying in this example is correct. It seems there may not be such linear order. Is there any positive integer for which such a linear extension is possible. For example for prime powers such extension is natural as I explain in the question. Thank you.

Comment: @RichardStanley Rather than looking for linear orders, should I look at chains in the divisor poset of arbitrary $n$ in order to generalize the result from $p^k$ to arbitrary $n$? But I am unable to see the analogue statement though. Kindly share your thoughts. Thank you.

Comment: Let $1=d_0,d_1,\dots,d_k=n$ be a maximal chain in the poset of divisors of $n$, so $d_i/d_{i-1}$ is a prime number $p_i$. This chain satisfies your property if and only if $n$ is divisible by $p_k^2$.

Comment: @RichardStanley Can you please explain what is $p_k$? Thank you.

Comment: I defined $p_i$ to be $d_i/d_{i-1}$, so $p_k=d_k/d_{k-1}$.

Comment: @RichardStanley Sorry. My mistake. I didn't noticed that. Thanks for the clarification.